# Must we release ivar in dealloc even if we don't own (alloc/new/copy) that ivar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

Must we release ivar in dealloc even if we don't own (alloc/new/copy) that ivar?

For example, is this correct?

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [_aUIImageIvar release];

    [super dealloc];
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _aUIImageIvar = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Never release something you don't own. But why aren't you retaining the image?

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy, I forget to retain it... It's because I didn't use setter, so it's easy to forget the retain.

Comment: Simple rules such as retain-release pairing get easily confused with other things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should only `release` those items that you've retained (or otherwise own). But it makes no sense to create an autorelease object and doing nothing with it that will retain it, because it will get released when the pool is drained.

Consider your line:

```
_aUIImageIvar = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

That returns an autorelease object and, as you point out, because you don't own it (e.g. you don't `retain` it or create it with `alloc`/`init`), it will be deallocated when the autorelease pool is drained (i.e. probably before you use it) and you'll end up with a dangling pointer to a deallocated object.

Clearly, you could remedy this by adding a `retain`, but it would be more logical to create it with `alloc`/`init`:

```
_aUIImageIvar = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Then you'll get an object with `retainCount` of one, and it will be retained for you (and then your `dealloc` method will then be correct). But the construct of creating an autoreleased object, and not doing anything with it that would `retain` it, makes no sense.

Comment: To @Rob, in fact, I have used property for `_profileImage`, so I can use `[self setProfileImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];` to implicitly retain it.

Comment: But `_aUIImageIvar = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];` is more logical if not using setter.

Comment: @congliu In that case, just remove the `release` in `dealloc` And you will be good. When `profileImage` is deallocated (you haven't shown us that, but I assume you're releasing that), that will reduce the retain count for this image.

Answer (score 4):

No.  In fact you must NOT release it.  Its strange that you don't retain it in your constructor.  Also, unless you have a good reason not to, you should probably move to using ARC.